# UIView on top of cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I have a cell on which I want to put a view like this:

```
 ------------------------------------------------

                     Cell 1 
                   ----------
                  |          |
 -----------------    View    -------------------
                  |          |
                   ----------

                     Cell 2
 ------------------------------------------------
```

But when I add it on cell 1, it ends up being like this because cell 2 hides half of it:

```
 ------------------------------------------------

                     Cell 1 
                   ----------
                  |   View   |
 ------------------------------------------------    



                     Cell 2
 ------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the `clipsToBounds` property:

```
cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Second, you need to have have the other cell to have a transparent background that is being drawn in the last possible moment:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

If this does not work, try the cell's `contentView` as well.